# Selenium select class does NOT throw error when it does not find item in the drop down list

Tags: java, selenium, select

I have method to select the item by visible text using Select class. The item I am passing in the parameter is not in the list. I want the test to fail and give me the error no such element found, but the selenium keeps on waiting for the item to appear and does not fail. Is there a way to forcefully fail the test and print the exception.

```
public static void selectAnItem(String elemetLocator, String itemToSelect){
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(elemetLocator)));
    try {
        select.selectByVisibleText(itemToSelect);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it does... you ate the error with your `catch`... what's the issue?

Comment: @JeffC Thanks. It worked now. I removed the try catch and saw it was taking couple of mins to fail and throw error.

Comment: OK. I'll add my comment as an answer so you can accept it so the question doesn't get left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are eating the exception with the `try-catch`. If you remove that, it should throw the error you are expecting.

One suggestion... rather than passing in a `String elementLocator`, pass in a `By` class. That will allow you to use more than just XPaths, e.g.

```
public static void selectAnItem(By locator, String itemToSelect)
{
    new Select(driver.findElement(locator)).selectByVisibleText(itemToSelect);
}
```

Now you can use `By.id()`, `By.cssSelector()`, and so on.